# Question on two different class extension patterns

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

What is the semantic difference between the following two methods:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this Array value)
{
    return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
}
```

and

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this T[] value)
{
    return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
}
```

Is there an advantage to one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first will work for *any* array, including rectangular arrays and ones with a non-zero lower bound. It will also work when the compile-time type of the array is just `Array`, which may happen very occasionally with fairly weakly-typed APIs.

In short, the first is more general, and should work anywhere that the second does.

(I'm assuming you *don't* want any "extra" features from this, such as extra constraints on `T` in the second form... you just want something which will find out whether an array reference is null or refers to an empty array.)

EDIT: For `IEnumerable`, you'd use:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    var iterator = value.GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        return !iterator.MoveNext();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Non-generic IEnumerator doesn't extend IDisposable
        IDisposable disposable = iterator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The *disadvantage* of this of course is that it can very easily have side-effects - for example, you could pass in a LINQ query which would end up talking to a database.

Comment: So would the first one be the preferred pattern?

Comment: @IanC: If you only want to target arrays, yes. You could make it more general by taking `IEnumerable` if you wanted to handle any *sequence*.

Comment: you are correct in that I don't want any extra functionality. This is the functional equivalent of string.IsNullOrEmpty(str).

Comment: how would I implement IEnumerable? It doesn't have a count or any facility for checking such.

Comment: thanks. Given what you said, I think I'll leave it at ICollection for now. It does what I need and in a generalized way, which is what I want.

Comment: On a total side note, @Jon, and purely out of curiosity, would there be a performance difference between using pattern 1, pattern 2, or ICollection?

Comment: @IanC: I suspect there would, but I doubt that it's significant and I wouldn't like to predict which way it would change :)

Answer (score 2):

With going generic you could add a conditional that further restricts what T can be...

So you could restrict it with "where T : class" or "where T : ISomeInterface" (most notably you could do "where T : IDisposable" and ensure that your extension can't use anything that can't dispose

Answer (score 1):

The second one uses generics hence is type safe.

Comment: So what are the ramifications on the first one (i.e. what could go wrong)?

Comment: Given that nothing within the body of the method uses any values, it's hard to see how type safety on an element basis is relevant.